# ggplot2 challenge: label specific points in complex cumulative abundance plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

We would like to mark specific points (proteins) in a graph representing the cumulative abundance of proteins in different cell development stages.
data: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/tynlfvsms41sh940pjz8o/dat.pro.mols.csv?rlkey=p62nwjv723c9b3c3xul0tk3ht&dl=0

Creation of the plot required us to build it iteratively and the code isnt very elegant. But it works.

```
dat.pro.mols %>% #mutate(value = cumsum(median_quant)/total_Quant) %>%
ggplot() +
geom_point(data = . %>% filter(stage == 'MB'), 
           aes(x= 1:3156, y= cum_Mol, ), color = "#0000e3") +
geom_point(data = . %>% filter(stage == 'PM'), 
           aes(x= 1:3156, y= cum_Mol, ), color = "#a043ec") +
geom_point(data = . %>% filter(stage == 'MC'), 
           aes(x= 1:3156, y= cum_Mol, ), color = "#a80092") +
geom_point(data = . %>% filter(stage == 'MM'), 
           aes(x= 1:3156, y= cum_Mol, ), color = "#ca0068") +
geom_point(data = . %>% filter(stage == 'B'), 
           aes(x= 1:3156, y= cum_Mol, ), color = "#ff7763") +
geom_point(data = . %>% filter(stage == 'PMN'), 
           aes(x= 1:3156, y= cum_Mol, ), color = "#c8a600") +
geom_hline(yintercept = 0.5, linetype="dashed",alpha=0.7) +
xlab("Protein rank by abundance") + 
ylab("Cumulative protein abundance") +
#ggtitle(stageOI) +
theme(legend.position = "none") +
xlim(0,70)
```

[image]

The graph shows the cumulative abundance of protein molecules in different cell stages and shows that some stages have a lot of different proteins making up 50% of their whole proteome.

But now we would like to label specific proteins (=SYMBOLS) to show how they move up or down in the proteome ranks and so far all trials failed to achieve this, so im putting it on SO as a ggplot challenge. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Non working code to add the labels:

```
  geom_text(data = . %>% filter(SYMBOL == 'ELANE'), aes(y= cum_Mol, x = cum_Mol, label = SYMBOL)) +
```

Expected result:
[image]

Comment: I don't think I understand yet what you want. Is there a way to articulate this with some simple sample data that can be included in the question instead of an external link?

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for your comment. I added a mock graph of the expected result. I will try to create a mock dataset but failed so far so I linked the external dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perhaps more a data issue than code one, although your code could be improved in several aspects.

To make it easier to explain, I generated two data frames: one for `geom_point()`, and the other for `geom_text()`

```
library(tidyverse)
dat.pro.mols <- read.csv("~/dat.pro.mols.csv")

df <- dat.pro.mols %>% 
  mutate(x = rep(1:3156, 6)) 

df_1 <- df %>% filter(SYMBOL == 'ELANE')

p <- df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x= x, y= cum_Mol, color = stage)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.5, linetype="dashed", alpha=0.7) +
  xlab("Protein rank by abundance") + 
  ylab("Cumulative protein abundance") +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  xlim(0, 70)+
  geom_text(data = df_1, aes(label = SYMBOL), color = "black") 

p
```

[image]

We can see any labels on this graph because your code included `xlim(0, 70)` while all x in df_1 data frame outside of this specified range.

```
> df_1
  UNIPROT SYMBOL stage molNr_vsn median_lg2 median_quant   cum_Mol    x
1  P08246  ELANE    MB      7961   24.90271     31366153 0.9727992 1031
2  P08246  ELANE    PM    190353   29.48223    749957247 0.7789084  147
3  P08246  ELANE    MC     77137   28.17904    303904147 0.9238254  316
4  P08246  ELANE    MM     97029   28.51004    382275729 0.9467212  271
5  P08246  ELANE     B     82259   28.27181    324087248 0.9545803  313
6  P08246  ELANE   PMN     87334   28.35817    344080365 0.9571961  284
```

Just to check this, we redefine xlim():

```
p + 
  xlim(0, NA) +
  geom_point(data = df_1, color = "red")
```

[image]

If you want to get exactly the same type of text labels, you may need to use `geom_text_repel()` function of `ggrepel`.